# Div classes are the wrong way round?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi i'm using Wordpress and Woocommerce and the Wootique theme.

I have two div classes one contains the login link and the other is a currency widget shortcode.

I want them on the same line like this:

```
Login/Register |CURRENCY BOX|
```

But currently they are switched round like this:

|CURRENCY BOX| Login/Register

I can't understand why they are switched round?

```css
.login {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin: auto;
}
.currency {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="login">
  <a href="http://casper-creations.com/my-account/">Login/Register</a>
</div>
<div class="currency">
  <?php echo do_shortcode( '[woocs]' );?>
</div>
```

I'm sure it's something simple but I've searched everywhere! Does anyone know why these div's are the wrong way around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing float: right everything is floating to the right. So the first element in the html is the most right, after that the second element sticks to the first element on the right.

```css
.login {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin: auto;
}
.currency {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="currency">
  Your currency
</div>
<div class="login">
  <a href="http://casper-creations.com/my-account/">Login/Register</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because they are set to float:right, the top div will be the right-most div. To switch them around, simply reorder the html as such:

```
<div class="currency">
  <?php echo do_shortcode( '[woocs]' );?>
</div>
<div class="login">
  <a href="http://casper-creations.com/my-account/">Login/Register</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you float items, that item gets pushed immediately to the right, ignoring other normal 'block' items.

IF you have two items side by side that are floated right, the first item your code comes across, will be fixed to the right, and will stay there.

If the next item also is set to float right, it will take the next available space to the previously floated items.

Answer (score 0):

You could opt to use positioning instead of floating elements:

```css
.login {
  display: inline-block;
  position:absolute;
  margin: auto;
 right:30px;
}
.currency {

  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="login">
  <a href="http://casper-creations.com/my-account/">Login/Register</a>
</div>
<div class="currency">
  <?php echo do_shortcode( '[woocs]' );?>
  £/$
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the currency and your login button into a wrapper class, float it right and display the containing elements `inline-block`

**SNIPPET**

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
.wrap {
  float: right;
}
.login {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
  background: #CCCCCC;
  padding: 10px;
}
.login a {
  color: #383838;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.currency {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #000000;
  padding: 10px;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="login"> <a href="http://casper-creations.com/my-account/">Login/Register</a>

  </div>
  <div class="currency">
    <p>Currency</p>
  </div>
</div>
```